# Adding values to cells in a specific column in HTML

Tags: python, html, django, web, web-applications

I am creating a very basic table in HTML for my Django project.
I got some help from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75011084/generating-new-html-rows-for-each-document-from-firestore-in-python-django/75011558#75011558) to learn how to pass a list from my Django app to my HTML and generate rows for my values.
My question this time is: how can I target the second, third, or any particular column for my list? For example, suppose I have a list of values and want to add all of them to Column 3 of my table.
Here is the code I tried to use where i wanted to have {{ name }} values added to column two, but it keeps adding the cells to the first column

```
<html>
   <body>   
           <table border="1" cellpadding = "5" cellspacing="5"> 
               <tr>
                   <th> IDs </th>
                   <th> Names </th>
                   <th> Heights </th>
                 </tr>
               {% for id in myIDs %}
                   <tr> 
                      <td>{{ id }}</td>
                      
                   </tr>
               {% endfor %}
               <tr>
                   {% for name in myNames %}
                   <td>
                       <tr> 
                           <td>{{ name }}</td>      
                        </tr>
                   </td>    
                       {% endfor %}
               </tr>
               </table>           
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For combining the data in tuples, you can use zip and for loop

Example:

```
MyIds = [1, 2, 3]
MyNames = [4, 5, 6]
MyHeights = [7, 8, 9]
data = []

for i, m, h in zip(MyIds, MyNames, MyHeights):
    data.append((i, m, h))
```

At the end, data will look like this -

```
 [(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. both answers helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

For each id, name and height, create a tuple.

Then create a empty list and append the tuples to the data.

Then send the data as context

```
temp = (id, name, height)
data = []
data.append(temp)
return render(request, 'index.html', {data: data})
```

Now in the html page

```html
{% for id, name, height in data %}
<tr>
    <td>{{id}}</td>
    <td>{{name}}</td>
    <td>{{height}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem with this approach and please correct me if I am wrong, is that the IDs will all combined as one object (id) and all of the IDs will output as one cell and same goes for names and height

Comment: I am assuming each record is a person's data with a unique id, name and height.
So store each record as tuple and store it in a list.
So IDs won't be combined in a single object but each ID will be combined with its corresponding name and height as a single object aka tuple
And you would send a list of this objects

Comment: Sorry I think I had to be more clear about the structure of my data. I am usin nosql database(firestore) and I have each value saved in a separate document for orgnizational purposes so what I am doing is that I have multiple queries for id-names-heights-so on.. so at the end I have few lists with each list containing the values. (MyIDs has all the IDS) and so on. What I wanted to do is sending each one of those lists to a column in HTML so that I will have a column for IDS, names and the rest.